# I want the standard deviation calculated in minutes

Tags: python, numpy, standard-deviation

My dataset is in hours and I need guidance on how to convert the standard deviation from hours to minutes.

In the code provided under, I only get the standard deviation for hours. How can I convert it to minutes?

```
np.sum(data['Time']*data['kneel']/sum(data['Time']))*60

data['kneel'].std()
```

Comment: I am not sure what data["Time"] and data["kneel"] are? So maybe I am misunderstanding what you need, but standard deviation is directly proportional to data so if you have standard deviation in hours and you want it in minutes you can multiply by 60:  data['kneel'].std()*60.

Comment: Hi, can you add a small sample of what `data` is like so we can reproduce the issue: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, i wanted to calculate cosine distance fast so I used the following solutions.
Try using **Dask**, it is pretty fast compared to pandas, moreover, you can also try **numba**, it basically makes python code computationally fast.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).